# Bufferedimage resize

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am trying to resized a bufferedimage. I am able to store it and show up on a jframe no problems but I can't seem to resize it. Any tips on how I can change this to make it work and show the image as a 200*200 file would be great

```
private void profPic(){
    String path = factory.getString("bottle");
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
}


public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH) {  
    int w = img.getWidth();  
    int h = img.getHeight();  
    BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, img.getType());  
    Graphics2D g = dimg.createGraphics();  
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);  
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newW, newH, 0, 0, w, h, null);  
    g.dispose();  
    return dimg;  
}
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

*Updated answer*

I cannot recall why [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9417836/1) worked but having tested it in a separate environment, I agree, the original accepted answer doesn't work (why I said it did I cannot remember either). This, on the other hand, did work:

```
public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH) { 
    Image tmp = img.getScaledInstance(newW, newH, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics2D g2d = dimg.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();

    return dimg;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't compile - getScaledInstance returns an Image not a BufferedImage.

Comment: The example I used was extracted from a working example I have, but yes, this wouldn't compile as is. I'll update this now.

Comment: Still not safe - on my Macbook, e.g., I get a ClassCastException - it's not a guaranteed conversion.

Comment: This doesn't work, you cannot cast Image, which is result of getScaledInstance, into BufferedImage.

Comment: @I82Much Write once, run anywhere... Ahem.

Comment: I get exception: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage

Comment: why is this listed as the correct answer when it doesn't work.

Comment: @Alex this is normal, because a solid color when resized by, say, 2* width and 2* height will result in the surrounding colors being "smeared" with the color to make the image seem more "smooth" and less chunky.

Comment: Why `TYPE_INT_ARGB` and not `img.getType()`?

Comment: The reason the first one doesn't compile is because the getScaledInstance() returns a ToolkitImage, not an Image. The reason an Image can be cast to a BufferedImage is be cause Image is a superclass of BufferedImage, not ToolkitImage.

Answer (score 22):

If all that is required is to resize a `BufferedImage` in the `resize` method, then the [Thumbnailator](http://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/) library can do that fairly easily:

```
public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH) {
  return Thumbnails.of(img).size(newW, newH).asBufferedImage();
}
```

The above code will resize the `img` to fit the dimensions of `newW` and `newH` while maintaining the aspect ratio of the original image.

If maintaining the aspect ratio is not required and resizing to exactly the given dimensions is required, then the `forceSize` method can be used in place of the `size` method:

```
public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH) {
  return Thumbnails.of(img).forceSize(newW, newH).asBufferedImage();
}
```

---

Using the [`Image.getScaledInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29) method will not guarantee that the aspect ratio of the original image will be maintained for the resized image, and furthermore, it is in general very slow.

Thumbnailator uses a technique to progressively resize the image which can be [several times faster than `Image.getScaledInstance`](http://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/wiki/Comparison) while achieving an image quality which generally is comparable.

*Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of this library.*

Comment: Thumbnailator awesome.!

Answer (score 6):

Here's some code that I have used to resize bufferedimages, no frills, pretty quick:

```
public static BufferedImage scale(BufferedImage src, int w, int h)
{
    BufferedImage img = 
            new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    int x, y;
    int ww = src.getWidth();
    int hh = src.getHeight();
    int[] ys = new int[h];
    for (y = 0; y < h; y++)
        ys[y] = y * hh / h;
    for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        int newX = x * ww / w;
        for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            int col = src.getRGB(newX, ys[y]);
            img.setRGB(x, y, col);
        }
    }
    return img;
}
```

Comment: great method, but the proportions where not correct, when I divided the factor for the height by the squareroot of two it worked fine.. =)

Answer (score 4):

This class resize from a file and get the format name:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class ImageResizer {

public static void main(String as[]) throws IOException{

    File f = new File("C:/Users/samsungrob/Desktop/shuttle.jpg");

    byte[] ba = resize(f, 600, 600);

    IOUtils.write(ba, new FileOutputStream( new File("C:/Users/samsungrob/Desktop/shuttle_resized.jpg") ) );

}




public static byte[] resize(File file,
                            int maxWidth, int maxHeight) throws IOException{
    int scaledWidth = 0, scaledHeight = 0;

    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read((ImageInputStream) file );

    scaledWidth = maxWidth;
    scaledHeight = (int) (img.getHeight() * ( (double) scaledWidth / img.getWidth() ));

    if (scaledHeight> maxHeight) {
        scaledHeight = maxHeight;
        scaledWidth= (int) (img.getWidth() * ( (double) scaledHeight/ img.getHeight() ));

        if (scaledWidth > maxWidth) {
            scaledWidth = maxWidth;
            scaledHeight = maxHeight;
        }
    }

    Image resized =  img.getScaledInstance( scaledWidth, scaledHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

    BufferedImage buffered = new BufferedImage(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, Image.SCALE_REPLICATE);

    buffered.getGraphics().drawImage(resized, 0, 0 , null);

    String formatName = getFormatName( file ) ;

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    ImageIO.write(buffered,
            formatName,
            out);

    return out.toByteArray();
}


private static String getFormatName(ImageInputStream iis) {
    try { 

        // Find all image readers that recognize the image format
        Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
        if (!iter.hasNext()) {
            // No readers found
            return null;
        }

        // Use the first reader
        ImageReader reader = (ImageReader)iter.next();

        // Close stream
        iis.close();

        // Return the format name
        return reader.getFormatName();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    return null;
}

private static String getFormatName(File file) throws IOException {
    return getFormatName( ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file) );
}

private static String getFormatName(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    return getFormatName( ImageIO.createImageInputStream(is) );
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

This is a shortened version of what is actually happening in imgscalr, if you just want to use the "balanced" smoothing:

```
/**
 * Takes a BufferedImage and resizes it according to the provided targetSize
 *
 * @param src the source BufferedImage
 * @param targetSize maximum height (if portrait) or width (if landscape)
 * @return a resized version of the provided BufferedImage
 */
private BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage src, int targetSize) {
    if (targetSize <= 0) {
        return src; //this can't be resized
    }
    int targetWidth = targetSize;
    int targetHeight = targetSize;
    float ratio = ((float) src.getHeight() / (float) src.getWidth());
    if (ratio <= 1) { //square or landscape-oriented image
        targetHeight = (int) Math.ceil((float) targetWidth * ratio);
    } else { //portrait image
        targetWidth = Math.round((float) targetHeight / ratio);
    }
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(targetWidth, targetHeight, src.getTransparency() == Transparency.OPAQUE ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR); //produces a balanced resizing (fast and decent quality)
    g2d.drawImage(src, 0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight, null);
    g2d.dispose();
    return bi;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try the imgscalr library. Best lib i found- very fast, good quality and simple to use

```
BufferedImage thumbnail = Scalr.resize(image, 150);
```

Maven: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.imgscalr/imgscalr-lib

GitHub: https://github.com/rkalla/imgscalr

> Apache 2 License

Comment: That link leads to all sorts of shady internet locations. The answer is a good one. ;)

Comment: I would update my answer, but your comment gives me too much pleasure ^^ <3 so i think this is the right link: https://github.com/rkalla/imgscalr

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, it helps:

```
BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File(C:\image.jpg);

BufferedImage thumbnail = Scalr.resize(bImage,  Scalr.Method.SPEED, Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_WIDTH,
                                       750, 150, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);
```

Comment: Just to add, that this is Imgscalr library -> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.imgscalr/imgscalr-lib