# Loading Buffered Image to JLabel in JScrollPane

Tags: java, bufferedimage, mouselistener, mousewheel, zooming

I'm Java beginner trying to load a `.PNG` 8356 x 5092 pixels into a JFrame 720 x 600.

I can load the image but it is zoomed to the top left, wanting to make the `.PNG` fit into the JFrame and then be able to span with the mouse click and zoom with mouse scroll.

I have been looking for answers for about 2 weeks now but no avail.
Just wanting a good shove into the right direction...

Cheers

***EDIT***

Ok I got the Image to load and scale to size by doing:

```
public Image ScaledImage(Image img, int w, int h) {
    BufferedImage resizedImg = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = resizedImg.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    g2.dispose();

    return resizedImg;

}
```

and passing it over to the JLabel like:

```
BufferedImage Map = ImageIO.read(new File(.PNG-LOCATION));
     ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ScaledImage(Map, 720, 600));
            JLabel Label = new JLabel();
            Label.setIcon(icon);
```

Now just need help or guidance in zooming, click to drag

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried resizing the PNG?

Comment: No I haven't as I have no idea where to start

Comment: You could start by looking up "resize bufferedimage java" which might or might not lead you to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417356/bufferedimage-resize

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bufferedimage resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417356/bufferedimage-resize)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for resizing:

```
static BufferedImage createResizedCopy(Image originalImage, 
            int scaledWidth, int scaledHeight, 
            boolean preserveAlpha)
    {
        System.out.println("resizing...");
        int imageType = preserveAlpha ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
        BufferedImage scaledBI = new BufferedImage(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, imageType);
        Graphics2D g = scaledBI.createGraphics();
        if (preserveAlpha) {
            g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
        }
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, null); 
        g.dispose();
        return scaledBI;
    }
```

Use code above as:
`img2 = createResizedCopy(img, 720 , 600, true);` Where `img` is your original image and `img2` is the resized one.

To load `img` use: `img = ImageIO.read(new File("yourImagepath"));`

To show it in frame:

```
img2 = createResizedCopy(img, 720 , 600, true);
ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img2);
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
frame.setSize(720,600);
JLabel lbl=new JLabel();
lbl.setIcon(icon);
frame.add(lbl);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

More details can be found here:
[resizing image in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895829/resizing-image-in-java)